# Java homework help

Tags: java

I have this assignment that I've tried. But when I enter 1 it should not give any output as 1 is > 0 and 1 is not even but I still get output as:

```
Enter a +ve number
1
You entered 1
I'd asked for a +ve number :)
```

.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a +ve number");
      int number = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered "+number);
      if(number > 0)
         if(number %2 == 0)
             System.out.println("Number"+number+" is even and +ve");
         else
             System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be best to use the code formatting and remove the line numbers from your code to make it more readable

Comment: I've edited it so that the indentation matches the control structure of the code.  Oops, the answer looks a bit obvious now.

Comment: @user459246: May be it is type error.. use "public" before defining the class. e.g. public class Main

Comment: get your homework answers from accomplished experts. https://topnotchpapers.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your else actually belongs to the **2nd** `if` not the 1st `if` as the indentation shows.

```
if(cond1)
 if(cond2) 
else   // this else belongs to 2nd if not 1st if.
```

is same as:

```
if(cond1) {
 if(cond2) {
 } else {
 }
}
```

This is because the Java grammar says that ***an else belongs to the closest unmatched if to which it can possibly belong***.

If you want to match the else with first if you need to use parenthesis as:

```
if(cond1) {
 if(cond2) {
 } 
} else { 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check that the code actually follows the logic it ought to - indentation won't help you with flow control, that's what curly brackets `{}` are for.

Comment: This is why I always put braces even if there's only one line of code after the if clause.

Answer (score 5):

That would probably be because your `ifs` are interpreted like this:

```
if(number > 0)
    if(number %2 == 0)
        System.out.println("Number"+number+" is even and +ve");
    else
        System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
```

How's the computer supposed to know what you *mean*? You need to use brackets to make it unambiguous:

```
if(number > 0) {
    if(number %2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number"+number+" is even and +ve");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I get the following output when I enter 1:

```
Enter a +ve number
1
You entered 1
I'd asked for a +ve number :)
```

Which is reasonable as you first check

```
if (number > 0)
```

which is true for `number == 1` and then you check

```
if (number % 2 == 0)
```

which is false for `number == 1` thus the else branch is taken:

```
System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)")
```

Your code should probably look something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a +ve number");
int number = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered " + number);
if (number > 0) {
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("Number" + number + " is even and +ve");
} else {
    System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should try to debug (using eclipse maybe) 
add paranthesis after if(number > 0) statement to wrap inner if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I threw your code into Netbeans and had it auto format it for readability. Is this your intended logic flow? Because this is how the compiler sees your if statements alignment/nesting.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a +ve number");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered " + number);

        if (number > 0)
        {
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Number" + number + " is even and +ve");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 %2 == 1 so it's clear that it enters on the else branch

Answer (score 0):

its because your else statement is saying if its not even then say "i asked for a +ve number"

move it out of the if statement like this

```
     if(number > 0)
     {
         if(number %2 == 0)
         {
             System.out.println("Number"+number+" is even and +ve");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("I'd asked for a +ve number :)");
     }
```